# RDD Key-Value pair with composite value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate, rdd

I have here a toy data set for which I need to compute list of cities in each state and population of that state(sum of population of all the cities in that state)[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfLfG.png)

I want to do it using RDDs without using groupByKey and joins. My approach so far:

In this approach I used 2 separate key-value pairs and joined them.

```
val rdd1=inputRdd.map(x=>(x._1,x._3.toInt))
val rdd2=inputRdd.map(x=>(x._1,x._2))
val popn_sum=rdd1.reduceByKey(_+_)
val list_cities=rdd2.reduceByKey(_++_)
popn_sum.join(list_cities).collect()
```

Is it possible to get the same output with just 1 key-value pair and without any joins.
I have created a new key-value pair, but I do not know how to proceed to get the same output using aggregateByKey or reduceByKey with this RDD:

```
val rdd3=inputRdd.map(x=>(x._1,(List(x._2),x._3)))
```

I am new to spark and want to learn the best way get this output.

```
Array((B,(12,List(B1, B2))), (A,(6,List(A1, A2, A3))), (C,(8,List(C1, C2))))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don;t you use dataframe/dataset?

Comment: I am learning RDD programming. I thought before moving to dataframes it is important to learn this thoroughly, and it was asked in one of my interviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `inputRdd` is of type

```
inputRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, Int)]
```

Then you can achieve your desired result by simply using one `reduceByKey` as

```
inputRdd.map(x => (x._1, (List(x._2), x._3.toInt))).reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 ++ y._1, x._2+y._2))
```

and you can it with `aggregateByKey` as

```
inputRdd.map(x => (x._1, (List(x._2), x._3.toInt))).aggregateByKey((List.empty[String], 0))((x, y) => (x._1 ++ y._1, x._2+y._2), (x, y) => (x._1 ++ y._1, x._2+y._2))
```

## DataFrame way

Even better approach would be to use dataframe way. You can convert your rdd to dataframe simply by applying `.toDF("state", "city", "population")` which should give you

```
+-----+----+----------+
|state|city|population|
+-----+----+----------+
|A    |A1  |1         |
|B    |B1  |2         |
|C    |C1  |3         |
|A    |A2  |2         |
|A    |A3  |3         |
|B    |B2  |10        |
|C    |C2  |5         |
+-----+----+----------+
```

After that you can just use `groupBy`, and apply `collect_list` and `sum` inbuilt aggregation functions as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
inputDf.groupBy("state").agg(collect_list(col("city")).as("cityList"), sum("population").as("sumPopulation"))
```

which should give  you

```
+-----+------------+-------------+
|state|cityList    |sumPopulation|
+-----+------------+-------------+
|B    |[B1, B2]    |12           |
|C    |[C1, C2]    |8            |
|A    |[A1, A2, A3]|6            |
+-----+------------+-------------+
```

`Dataset` is almost the same but comes with additional type-safety

Comment: Wow... thanks. Can you please let me know how to do the same with aggregateByKey.

Comment: You should point out that this just won't scale, and has terrible time complexity.

Comment: What do you mean @user8371915. rdd's are already distributed and should be scalable isn;t it?

Comment: That's simple - check complexity of each merge operation (Scala library source will be useful here). Or even at the higher level, the number of `List` objects initialized. Just because something is distributed it doesn't mean it scales.

Comment: I can understand the memory issue and load to garbage collector but I don't agree with unscalability and time complexity of the answer

Comment: Thank you for helping me out :)